# Json response on php curl request

Tags: php, json, curl

I have sent a curl request, and I'm outputing the response this way.

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($output, true);
echo $output;
echo $json;
```

This is the output.

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created Server: nginx/1.15.8 Date: Wed, 02 Sep 2020 23:53:01 GMT Content-Type: application/json Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate Pragma: no-cache Expires: 0 X-Frame-Options: DENY Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains { "orderRef" : "4352fa96-05cc-400e-854c-808e5da7dfd7", "autoStartToken" : "84ead0b7-1ee8-40ed-be82-1168e7cbb16b", "message" : "" }
```

I'm trying to decode the json part, but $json is just null. I'd like to be able to read $json["autoStartToken"]. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Right now your curl request also return the header so you can't directly use json_decode with the respond, try putting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);` before the `curl_exec($ch)`

Comment: That made it. Thank you! :)

Comment: The default is to not include headers. So you must have a `curl_setopt()` that's setting it to `true`. Get rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

As [catcon mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63714989/json-response-on-php-curl-request/63715126#comment112669243_63714989):

> Right now your curl request also return the header so you can't directly use json_decode with the respond, try putting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);` before the `curl_exec($ch)`

Comment: Isn't that the default?